# mdadm fail, disk won't show up

Tags: raid, hard-drive, mdadm, debian-etch

One of my disks failed in my raid array:

`cat /proc/mdstat`:

```
Personalities : [raid1] 
md1 : active raid1 sda2[2](F) sdb2[1]
      488086720 blocks [2/1] [_U]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[0] sdb1[1]
      192640 blocks [2/2] [UU]
```

When i tried to remove then re-add the drive the following happened:

```
mdadm: hot removed /dev/sda2
host:# mdadm /dev/md1 --add /dev/sda2
mdadm: add new device failed for /dev/sda2 as 2: Invalid argument
```

`fdisk -l /dev/sda` returns nothing.

Can you tell me what's happening now, especially because `md0` looks fine. Tried to Google it but nothing interesting come up.

Update (just for verbatim), now `md0`is failed too:

```
Personalities : [raid1]
md1 : active raid1 sdb2[1]
     488086720 blocks [2/1] [_U]

md0 : active raid1 sda1[2](F) sdb1[1]
     192640 blocks [2/1] [_U]
```

Comment: Does `dmesg` or `/var/log/kern.log` shed any light on this with regards to drive errors?

Comment: @DerfK: Thank you. Looks like it's totally dead? `end_request: I/O error, dev sda, sector 976559000, md: disabled device sda2, could not read superblock.`

Comment: @upvoter: now is the time when i'm not too happy because of a +1 :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the `sda` drive is dead.  I'm guessing `md0` was for booting, which means it probably didn't get accessed much so its driver doesn't know sda1 is dead too.

Before you reboot the computer, **make sure that you've installed grub to sdb** since the BIOS probably isn't going to be able to boot off of that first drive.

If you didn't already do this, you'll need to run `grub`, then on grub's command prompt do:

```
root (hd1,0)
setup (hd1)
```

(From the guide [here](http://www.texsoft.it/index.php?c=hardware&m=hw.storage.grubraid1&l=it) for grub 0.95, I'm not sure if this has changed in newer versions of grub)  (Note: hd1 assumes that sdb is the second drive in the system, if you've mixed IDE (hda) and SATA/SCSI drives, then you might have to figure this one out on your own)

Comment: thank you for your detailed answer. I'm in really trouble now because the cube is about 200kms from me. Now i must to build a secondary server in a blazing fast speed and dump everything onto it. Thank you, again.

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `sda`. It's pooched.